# excluding based on related field's count

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, orm

I have classic title and entry models where title is foreignkey in entry model. I use users model's default `first_name` field to suspend users, so if a user is suspended then the `first_name` field is set to `blocked`. I also have a model to let user block eachother:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    blocker= models.ForeignKey("auth.user",on_delete= 
 models.CASCADE,related_name="blocker")
    blocked= models.ForeignKey("auth.user",on_delete= 
 models.CASCADE,related_name="blocked")
```

What I want to do is to display titles while excluding titles if there are no entries left belonging to the title after exclusion of blocked and suspended users. In other words, filtering titles if related entry count is > 0 after exclusions. I've been using the code below to solve this:

```
title= Popular.objects.all().order_by("-rating")
    titles= []
    followed_count= None

    paginator = Paginator(title, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        entries2 = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        entries2 = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        entries2 = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    
    page_list = entries2.paginator.page_range

    for title in entries2:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            followed_count= Entry.objects.filter(user__followed__follower=request.user,title=title.title,created_date__gte=date_from).exclude(user__last_name="blocked").count()
            blocked_count= Entry.objects.filter(user__blocked__blocker=request.user,title=title.title,created_date__gte=date_from).exclude(user__last_name="blocked").count()
        else:
            blocked_count= 0
        
        suspend_count= Entry.objects.filter(user__last_name="blocked",title=title.title,created_date__gte=date_from,).count()

        amount= Entry.objects.filter(title=title.title,created_date__gte=date_from).count()
        amount -= blocked_count + suspend_count
        if amount == 0:
            continue
        titles.append({"title":title.title,"url":title.title.title_url,"rating":title.rating,"title_id":title.title_id,"amount":amount,"followed_count":followed_count}
```

But if there are titles with no entries it causes the paginator to create empty pages, I also do not want to put the pagination code to the end as I don't want to iterate over and over the whole database.

Comment: You should be able to do this within the database. Check this out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

Comment: This problem comes from a wrong design. Your problem should be solved in the **model** part, but you are trying to solve it in the **view**. The problem with your current solution is not only that you'll have empty pages, but also you'll have pages with arbitrary number of records for example 1 record per page which does not sound good. So go to the model part and solve your problem there as suggested by @hendrikschneider.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if that is what @hendrikschneider suggested and also I don't really know what to fix in the models, Could you explain further?  Btw one result per page was set to test, so that's not related to the problem at all.